# Send HTTP Response from we server to client

Tags: java

I have a problem in sending the body of http response,and I think the problem in this line `out.write(buffer, 0, bytes);` please help me .

```
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(ClientConn.getInputStream());

    OutputStream ot = ClientConn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(ot);

    String request = din.readLine().trim();
    System.out.println(request);
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(request);

    String header = st.nextToken();
    System.out.println(header);
    if (header.equals("GET")) {
        String fileName = st.nextToken();
        String file = fileName.substring(1, fileName.length());
        System.out.println(file);
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        boolean fileExist = true;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            fileExist = false;
        }

        String ServerLine = "Simple HTTP Server";
        String StatusLine = null;
        String ContentTypeLine = null;
        String ContentLengthLine = null;
        String ContentBody = null;

        if (fileExist) {
            StatusLine = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK";
            ContentTypeLine = "Content-type: text/html";
            ContentLengthLine = "Content-Length: " + (new Integer(fin.available()).toString());
        } else {
            StatusLine = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK";
            ContentTypeLine = "Content-type: text/html";
            ContentBody = "<HTML>" +
                    "<HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>" +
                    "<BODY>404 Not Found" +
                    "</BODY></HTML>";
            ContentLengthLine = (new Integer(ContentBody.length()).toString());
        }

        out.write(StatusLine.getBytes());
        out.write(ServerLine.getBytes());
        out.write(ContentTypeLine.getBytes());
        out.write(ContentLengthLine.getBytes());
        // output.writeUTF(file);
        if (fileExist) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes = 0;
            while ((bytes = fin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytes);

                for (int iCount = 0; iCount < bytes; iCount++) {
                    int temp = buffer[iCount];
                    System.out.print((char) temp);
                }
            }

        }

        out.flush();
        fin.close();
    } else {
        //out.write(ContentBody.getBytes());
    }

    out.close();
    ClientConn.close();
```

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? What's the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header is not properly written into the `OutputStream`, you forget to write the `EOL` characters which are `"\r\n"` at the end of each line. And before starting to write the content of your body you need to write the `EOL` characters too.

In other words, you need to do something like this:

```
String eol = "\r\n";
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ASCII");
byte[] eolBytes = eol.getBytes(charset);
out.write(StatusLine.getBytes(charset));
out.write(eolBytes);
out.write( ServerLine.getBytes(charset));
out.write(eolBytes);
out.write(ContentTypeLine.getBytes(charset));
out.write(eolBytes);
out.write( ContentLengthLine.getBytes(charset));
out.write(eolBytes);
// End of the header
out.write(eolBytes);
// Here the body begin
```

Indeed your header must be encoded into `ASCII`.

**Response update:**

Other remarks regarding your code:

1. Use the method [File#exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) to check if a file exist.
2. Use `Files.getAttribute(Paths.get("/path/to/my/file"), "size")` to get the size of your file
3. In case the file doesn't exist you just don't write the body in your current code.

Comment: Thank you very much , it runs successfully

Comment: we try write file not exist in the url to test 404 error appear but it will give me this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at http_server.HttpRequest.process(HttpRequest.java:126)
 at http_server.Http_server.main(Http_server.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I added some remarks in my response hoping that it can help

Comment: 1. for now you use a try/catch block to check if the file exist, it is not the proper way. 2. For now you rely on available() to get the size of the file which is not the proper way before available returns the total amount of bytes that can be read before being blocked 3. Your code is incomplete, you never write the content of ContentBody when fileExist is false